# How to refer to IsloatedStorage folder in VB6?

Tags: windows, vb6, isolatedstorage

How do you refer to the `IsolatedStorage` folder in VB6?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do it by creating a .NET class library that accesses IsolatedStorage and then exposing the resulting assembly as a COM library through the interop layer.

Here's an MSDN article that might help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Isolated Storage is called "isolated", because it can only be accessed by the owning software, which as far as I know, must be a .NET based software.

Because VB6 isn't .NET Based, I don't think that this is possible at all.

Comment: There are no security restrictions preventing VB6 getting access to Isolated Storage: from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx#scenarios_for_isolated_storage) "isolated storage is not protected... from unmanaged code" and VB6 is unmanaged. So it's certainly possible, although it might be fiddly to *actually find* some specific part of isolated storage underneath the [top-level directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx#isolated_storage_locations)